# Draw a race track with d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

For the needs of a small personnal game, I must draw a race track as a SVG path. For this, I thought the use D3.js library that seems to fit my needs perfectly, but I can not seem to find a way to achieve what I want to do. 
My circuit is in the following form, and serve my game engine to calculate the speed and behavior of cars. It is simply a sequence of straight lines and curves

```
"sectors": [
    {
        "length": 300,
        "type": "line"
    },
    {
        "length": 18,
        "type": "curve",
        "radius": 11,
        "angle": 86,
        "turn" : 'right'
    },
    {
        "length": 100,
        "type": "line"
    }
```

]

I tried to use naively D3.js and I was able to draw several paths that correspond to each sector of the circuit: straight lines and arcs. Now I want to find a way to join all these elements butt, so draw my final circuit.
I followed the tutorial on the next page (https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) and I can well create a path consisting of several lines that represent the different straight lines of my circuit with a code like this :

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d) { return d.length; })
                     .y(function(d) { return 0; })
                     .interpolate("linear");

var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(mySectors))
                        .attr("stroke", "blue")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("fill", "none");
```

But how I can switch between drawing lines and curves?

A big thank you in advance to those who read this and who can provide me an answer

Raccoon

---

I found something like this :

```
path = svg.append("path")
   .datum(points);


path.attr("d", function (d) {
   var lines = new Array();

   for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
       lines.push([d[i][0], d[i][1]]);
   }
   return line(lines);
})
```

Is it a good track ?

---

I try this, but i doesn't works... Any idea ?

```
svg.append("path")
            .datum(formatSectors)
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                var paths = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                    if (d[i].type === 'line') {
                        var lineData = [{"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": d[i]['distance'], "y": d[i]['distance']}]
                        paths.push(lineFunction(lineData));
                    }
                    if (d[i].type === 'curve') {
                        var curveData = {"radius": d[i].radius, "angle": d[i].angle};
                        var arcData = arcFunction(curveData);
                        paths.push(arcData);
                    }
                }
                return paths;
            })
            .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("fill", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

d3 might be more than you need.  You should look at the svg path syntax https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

You can try it out at https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ

you will have to translate your data into values that correspond to svg path commands, but it should be pretty straight forward.

```
M 100 300 L 400 300 A 11 11 0 1 1 400 418 L 300 418
```

describes the three segments you have above, except I made up the arc stuff :) because I didn't do the math.

M 100 300 -- move without drawing to the point 100, 300 
L 400 300 -- draw a line to 400, 300 (length 300)
A 11 11 0 1 1 400 418 -- using radius x and y of 11 and 11, with no rotation, and sweep flags set, draw an arc to point 400, 418
L 300 418 -- draw a line to 300, 418 (length 100)